# Create models and relationship for two new tables in DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.3

I has two table Post(id, text, id_tag) and Tag(id, name).
How create relationship for two this table and how create models for work framework with this table.

Comment: For the Model `php artisan make:model ModelName` use in command
AND Go https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins

Answer (score 0):

You should create two model 1) Tag 2) Post like:

1) Tag

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\frontend;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes; //<--- use the softdelete traits

  protected $dates = ['deleted_at']; //<--- new field to be added in your table

  /**
   * The database table used by the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = 'tag';

  /**
   * The database primary key value.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $guarded = ['id', '_token'];

  /**
   * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = ['name'];



  /**
   * That belong to the Tag.
   */
  public function post()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
  }
}
```

2) Post

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
  use SoftDeletes; //<--- use the softdelete traits

  protected $dates = ['deleted_at']; //<--- new field to be added in your table

  /**
   * The database table used by the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = 'post';

  /**
   * The database primary key value.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $guarded = ['id', '_token'];

  /**
   * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = ['text','id_tag'];

  /**
   * The roles that belong to the Post.
   */
  public function tag()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tag','id_tag');
  }
}
```

Hope this work for you !!!